# Broken "Awarded for" links in badge popups

Tags: bug, badges, profile-page, popup

Today while I was viewing a user's activity tab in their profile, I noticed that the newest badge he achieved was [**Cleanup**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4/cleanup).

I clicked on the badge and a popup showed with a link for the post which the badge was awarded.

[image]

---

The actual post was deleted, thus the link is pretty much useless here. Moreover when I click on *Learn More* option, it showed ***post deleted or otherwise unavailable***.

[image]

---

So, the *Awarded for:* link in badges should not be visible if the post is deleted unless it's the profile owner.

Answer (score 5):

Users with more than 10k reputation can see deleted posts.

The link is not useless. This is not a bug.

Comment: Then it should be shown to the users who have more than 10K rep. It's useless for the rest.

Comment: The interface is consistent, intentionally. Voting buttons are also shown for your own posts, despite you not being able to vote for them.

Comment: I think from a UX perspective, the links should be hidden. Why show something which the user can't see?

Comment: @Script47 Personally, I think it would add unnecessary complexity and checks. The link exists, it tells me the name of the post, and if I follow it it tells me it was deleted since. The same way comment flag links are shown even when you can't use it because you need to wait 5 seconds, or the voting buttons when you can no longer undo your vote. This way the interface is the same for everyone, and informs users just by existing.

Comment: @yivi Fair enough, each to their own I guess.